# Suggestions on how to slant a question about environmental conditions so that it would be on topic on TGO?

Tags: discussion

I was intrigued by the question [Swimming in a river in England or Wales with a right of navigation](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16331/swimming-in-a-river-in-england-or-wales-with-a-right-of-navigation) because there was a tacit assumption that most rivers in England, Wales and Scotland -- or most parts of most rivers -- were what the U.S. Clean Water Act calls swimmable/fishable.

Obviously we can't have a multitude of questions asking if the portion of river **R** in country **C** from point **A** to point **B** is swimmable/fishable by USCWA standards, but questions about how water quality affects outdoor activities should be on-topic.  We have several questions about giardia and drinking from streams in the wilderness, but that seems to be it.

I am just wandering here, and hope there are some more pointed thoughts on how to bring water quality -- and air quality -- into our forum.

As an example:  Would a question about what percentage of river length (this would have to be qualified or defined in some way) in England was safe to swim in, and whether environmentally non-swimmable stretches were posted or otherwise indicated, be on topic?

And of course, immediately after I posted this Meta question, I saw this very focussed question on water quality: [What are the most likely causes of unfilterable water contamination in upland UK areas?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16345/what-are-the-most-likely-causes-of-unfilterable-water-contamination-in-upland-uk).  Are good, focused questions like this the only way to go?

Comment: Interesting question ab2, and congrats for reaching over 7,000 rep!

Comment: I'd like to add my congratulations to Sue's, and reassure you that you can swim in almost all rivers in the UK without too much fear of illness. The Thames gets a bit dodgy down by London, and other major cities have the same problem, but upstream of them is usually ok.

Comment: In my opinion narrow and clear questions are much better than broad ones as the suggested question about percentage - what real use is that? A question about whether and how non-swimmable areas are identifiable would be good again after this standard: Does the answer have real value in the outdoors.